# Notes not played by Kontakt virtual instrument

Tags: reaper, kontakt

I have a midi clip with 1/16 notes. Certain virtual instruments do not have problems playing it, however Kontakt basses do not play these notes. I added longer notes and they are played. Is there a setting on the instrument or in tje DAW which could be changed to solve this?
(Reaper, 150bpm)

Update: The midi clips are imported from a midi file. New notes added are played even when they are short.

Comment: just increase the length of the notes until they get played.

Comment: It will be a different song then.

Comment: You can still leave the note-on events where they are, just lengthen the distance between note-on and note-off. I get that it will be a different song - it will have a bass line!

Answer (score 1):

Solved: I needed to change midi channel from the midi notes in midi clips. I'm not sure why were they played by certain instruments.